# continue creating files from where it stopped

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I am using python and I have to write a program to create files of a total of 160 GB. I ran the program overnight and it was able to create files of 100 GB. However, after that it stopped running and gave an error saying "No space left on device".

QUESTION : I wanted to ask if it was possible to start running the program from where it stopped so I don't have to create those 100 GB files again.

Comment: It's impossible to say. We have no way of imagining your code.

Comment: you can create index for file. after raise a exception record the index number

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: how do i do it @martineau

Comment: By saving the information somewhere — in a file — and looking for it at start-up. You'd need to make sure to delete it when the program finishes normally, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of your position in what you're doing with a `currentPosition` list, since lists are mutable, you can modify it within your function to keep track.

```
def foo():
    currentPosition = 0
    while currentPosition < endPosition
        try:
            createTonsOfData() # global currentPosition
        except IOError:
            raw_input('Ran out of space, press Enter to continue')
            continue
```

Comment: So you're recommending the use of a global variable. Regardless, an `int` would work just as well if you declared `global currentPosition` in the function.

Comment: That's very true @martineau, I'll edit my answer to reflect that! Without knowing how the function works, the only ways to store where you are, that I can think of, are use of an external source (ie. disk, database, etc) or use of a global variable. This seems like a more elegant way to handle it, rather than using an external source.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that the program quits running at some point, so whatever is in memory (regardless of how it's stored or what it is) will be lost. That data _must_ be stored somewhere more permanent...

Answer (score 0):

More details are required i think. how are these files being created? What are the stop conditions for your function? If you are doing a simple file writer you can change the mode to append and that should help. Anyway, a little more details are required

Have a good one